# Lighting LED using keypad and microcontroller

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, led, keypad

So I am working with Gizduino (Arduino clone), keypad and led. What am I doing is getting the value of keypressed and then light up the led according to the value (eg., when I pressed 2 on the keypad 2 LEDs will blink). I know this is just basic but please bear with me. I have this code (I will not include some really basic things like keymapping or something that is not related to my question).

```
int led1 = A0;
int led2 = A1;

void setup()
{


pinMode(led1, OUTPUT);
pinMode(led2, OUTPUT);


}

void loop()
{
   char keypressed = myKeypad.getKey();

   if(keypressed != NO_KEY)
   {

       if(keypressed > 47 && keypressed < 58)  // is between '0' and '9'
       {
           if(!mySwitch)
           {
               num1 = (num1 * 10) + (keypressed - 48);
           }
           else
           {
               num2 = (num2 * 10) + (keypressed - 48);
           }

           if(keypressed = '1')
           {
               digitalWrite(led1, HIGH);
               delay(500);
               digitalWrite(led1,LOW);
               delay(500);
           }
           if(keypressed = '2')
           {

               digitalWrite(led2, HIGH);
                delay(500);
               digitalWrite(led2,LOW);
               delay(500);

        }
    }
}
```

What's happening is that when I press '1' in the keypad the first led will blink and after that the second one will too. Why is this happening? Is there a problem in my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equality testing operator is `==`, the assignment operator is `=`.

You are using = instead of == so the if condition returns always true.

This line `if(keypressed == '1')` assigns character 1 to the `keypressed` variable, since  `keypressed` becomes a non zero value the if condition is always true.

The code should be like:

```
if(keypressed == '1')
{
    digitalWrite(led1, HIGH);
    delay(500);
    digitalWrite(led1, LOW);
    delay(500);
}

if(keypressed == '2')
{

    digitalWrite(led2, HIGH);
    delay(500);
    digitalWrite(led2, LOW);
    delay(500);

}
```

Comment: @NewInEverything  It's a very common mistake, and the more complex the code the harder to find. Usually the compiler gives a warning is cases where a = is used instead of == so it's a good idea to keep an eye on the compiler report.

Comment: The compiler dint give a warning though.

Comment: @NewInEverything Indeed it doesn't, I just did a test in Arduino 1.5.5. I mainly write my code in AVRstudio and there I get a warning as expected `warning: suggest parentheses around assignment used as truth value`.

Comment: @NewInEverything According to http://stackoverflow.com/q/7803443/3080173 the warnings seem to be disabled (although it refers to an older version so maybe things are different).

Comment: Sorry for asking, but what will I do to a code should i copy it and paste it to one of the text file in the arduino folder, if it is what file should i replace?

Comment: @NewInEverything I didn't get you, what code are you referring to? If you mean the python code shown in the linked question it's intended to compile a modified version of avr-g++. I can't help you how exactly to proceed.